# Tomcat 7 and Java EE 6.0 javax.annotation.sql package

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am trying to use the new Java EE 6.0 annotations to define a DataSource within a Java Servlet. For instance: @DataSourceDefinition annotation. But it seems Tomcat 7.0.x doesn't support it because I am not able to compile the code against its libraries.

I have searched Apache Tomcat web site to find any information about this point with no luck.

So my questions are:

- Do you confirm me that Tomcat 7.0.x doesn't support javax.annotation.sql package?
- Any idea if it will support it?
- Any workaround to have such support in Tomcat while the official support comes in?

Comment: Rephrase your question, emphasising the "not able to compile the code against its libraries" part. What are you trying to compile?  What's on your classpath?

Comment: Well, I am trying to compile a Java Servlet that tries to use DataSourceDefinition annotation.  In my classpath I have all tomcat 7.0.22 libraries (JARs located at /lib directory). And the compiler complains with DataSourceDefinition cannot be resolved to a type.  It works fine with other annotations like WebServlet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat only implements Servlet and JSP. `@DataSourceDefinition` is in common annotations (JSR 250), which Tomcat choose not to support.

You might want to try [TomEE](http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) insead.

Comment: Tomcat does implement Common Annotations since Tomcat 6. See Tomcat `lib/annotations-api.jar`.

Comment: @Arendv.Reinersdorff It does, but does `@DataSourceDefinition` DO anything? The `data-source` element in web.xml also validates, but does it DO anything? Please try it and let us know ;)

Comment: @ArjanTijms I haven't tried it, but I'm pretty sure that it doesn't do anything. You make a good point. Chemi did ask about a compilation error, but merely compiling the application probably won't help him if Tomcat doesn't create a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in Tomcat](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55534), Tomcat's `lib/annotations-api.jar` was not updated for changes in Commons annotations.

Update Tomcat 7 or 8 to the latest version to see the `@DataSourceDefinition` annotation.

EDIT

As Arjan Tijms points out, the annotation is included in Tomcat, but probably not supported. Tomcat probably won't create a datasource if you use it.